# Using Unicode in latex math (case)

Tags: fontspec, unicode, unicode-math

How can i write a case math like this?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/R2F1fWq.png]

i tried:

```
\begin{align}
BP = \begin{cases}  1 & nếu \space c > r \\e^{1-\frac{r}{c}} & nếu c \leq r \end{cases}
\end{align}
```

but it does not work: the string "nếu", which contains a unicode-encoded glyph, displays incorrectly!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've removed a couple of your tags as you weren't asking about biblatex or the editor itself. Remember the tags tell us what your question is about. So if you had a question *about* Texpad (like, 'how do I alter the syntax highlighting in Texpad?') you would tag it with Texpad.  But you wouldn't if you just happened to be using Texpad as your editor. Anyway, that's just a quick heads-up, well done for including the proper code sample markdown and I hope someone who knows the answer will be along soon :)

Comment: Please complete your code so that we can compile it to reproduce the same incorrect output. Please also tell us which engine you are using. I assume XeTeX or LuaTeX since you're using `unicode-math`. We need a complete example to see the details e.g. the fonts you are specifying etc. Are you sure that should not be marked up as text e.g. with `\text{}`?

Comment: I can only reproduce the output you are showing by using `\text{}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I originally misread your question and saw the character you'd typed as an `e` with a tilde accent. However, I now see it is really a to bach and an acute. So, for these two accents on the `e`, I believe you want something like this which typesets the character in text mode rather than maths mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
BP = \begin{cases}  1 & \text{nếu } c > r \\e^{1-\frac{r}{c}} & \text{nếu } c \leq r \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: another possibility]

I'd like to know how to type this, though. (Other than copy-pasting from your question!)

Comment: It should be a circumflex with an acute above it. You can make it out of combining diacritical marks, does ế not copy across for you?

Comment: @Au101 It just isn't very easy to see it is meant to be that with my eyes and my screen, I think. I actually was editing when you commented. Please see above. But I'd still like to know how to type it.

Comment: You need maybe a Vietnamese keyboard layout or you can do it by unicode character codes, or with a character map. For me with an international keyboard AltGr+; AltGr+' e - to my surprise - does work ế but I originally made it using Ubuntu's "Character Map" I guess Windows might have something similar. OS X does but I can't remember what it's called

Comment: And yes, sorry, I didn't mean to come across as brusque, your original cut ended with a sentence saying you weren't quite sure what it was and I meant my comment as a natural reply to that. I certainly didn't mean to sound like I was thinking "silly cfr" !

Comment: If you're interested by the way, the vowel ê is pronounced like Welsh *c**e**lyn* but shorter. Where it has the acute on it, this is a tone mark indicating that the tone of the voice rises sharply from a mid tone to a high tone

Comment: @Au101 I wrote that and then had second thoughts and peered very closely at the screen. The acute was shifted to the right so it joined up with the little roof (circumflex). Thanks for the info. How do you know the Welsh for holly? I tried AltG+^;AltG+';e but I just got a to mawr (big roof) rather than a little roof or an acute. I don't know if Ubuntu's character map is specific to Ubuntu or not. A laptop keyboard doesn't make it easier, I guess ;).

Comment: +1. Observe that what's really needed for this code to compile is the `fontspec` package, which is loaded automatically by the `unicode-math` package: the string `nếu` occurs in text mode rather than in math mode. Incidentally, I would delete the upper (original) part of the answer since it appears to have been based on a simple misreading of a character.

Comment: @cfr It's a very easy mistake to make :) Honestly, regarding my Welsh vocab, [Wikipedia was my friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_orthography). Apparently [there is a Windows Character Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map_(Windows)) although I'm afraid I can't vouch for it. That works very well for one-off uses, but if you actually wanted to type out [some Vietnamese](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map) you'd definitely wanna find a Vietnamese keyboard layout to download

Comment: @Mico Yes, you're right. Initially, I was confused by the fact that the answer was accepted in its original state. But I think that is because the `\text{}` fixed the problem either way. It is the `\text{...}` bit which the OP needed, I think. They already had `fontspec` via `unicode-math`.

Comment: @Au101 I'm afraid a Windows solution wouldn't help me. Most likely Ubuntu's Character Map is available for other distros in some form or other. But if I ever learn Vietnamese, I'll remember to look out a keyboard ;).

Comment: The "Character Map" is actually GNOME specific, I think, rather than distro specific. KDE apparently has KCharSelect, anyway, we're getting a bit off topic ... :P

Comment: @Au101 Aha! that is helpful, albeit off-topic. KCharSelect I *do* have :-).